How to compare contents from two flow files in apache nifi
I want to compare two flow files content line by line and get the delta out of it, I will be getting flow file data from connecting the database and my flow flies looks like below
1st flow file(Its a key value pair with ~ as the sapartor)
123|3~abc|123|Hyderabad
456|3~abc|456|delhi
789|3~abc|789|delhi

2nd flow flow file
1234|3~abc|123|Hyderabad
456|3~abc|456|delhi
789|3~abc|789|chennai

My output after finding the delta will be like below
   1234|3~abc|123|Hyderabad(123 is changed to 1234)
   789|3~abc|789|chennai(delhi is changed to chennai)

I might have thousands of lines like this, So could you please help me which inbuilt processors i can use to achieve this task or do i need to use groovy script, thank you

Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Hi @cfrick, thank you for the response, I have tried to use the jointenrichment processor but unfortunately it didn't work well , because in joinenrichment processor , the original and the enrich file data will be the same,but where as in my scenario i am getting the two different flow flies from the data base
